# How do I print lines in a file only where second and second last character are the same?

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I want to print all the lines of a file in which second and second last character are the same, such as with the following file (comments to the right are for explanatory purposes, they do not exist in the file):

```
hello james        # second/second-last are 'ee' - match
how are you?       #                        'ou'
are you okay?      #                        'ry'
Is it past         #                        'ss' - match
```

Then the output should be

```
hello james
Is it past
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Have to mention it: The [accepted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/2648551) in jww's given link is very controversial. But glad there are other opinions, too. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grep` with grouping and backreference for this, e.g.:

```
 grep -x ".\(.\).*\1." f1.txt
```

This pattern looks in given order for:

- any character: `.`
- another arbitrary character in a capture group: `\(.\)`
- any number (including 0) of characters: `.*`
- the same character previously captured (the backreference): `\1`
- finally, the last arbitrary character: `.`

`-x` means it has to match the *whole* line rather than just some portion of it (same as using `--line-regexp`). As a result only the matched lines will be printed.

Comment: Yes!! It works. Thank You. But can you explain me this command

Comment: Thanks Bro for help

Comment: Can you tell how can i print even number of words from each line?

Comment: I mean to say is that to print even  no of words that is.. eg :                                                                           Hello World                                                                        Hi Friend                                                                                               Then the output is :                                                      World                                                                             Friend

Comment: Ah, got it. Better you ask another question for it, this is completely different and is going off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` that compare second first and second last character:

```
awk '{b=split($0,a,"")} a[2]==a[b-1]' file
hello james
Is it past
```

If there are spaces or tabs at the end of the line, it can be trimmed away like this:

```
awk '{$1=$1;b=split($0,a,"")} a[2]==a[b-1]'
hello james
Is it past
```